# Use MegaCli to reconstruct RAID on Dell PERC 5/i?

Tags: raid, dell, megaraid

I have a RAID 1 + hot spare that I would like to reconstruct, online, into a RAID 5 set.  I know this is possible with OpenManage, but I has anyone figured out how to pull this off using the MegaCli tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MegaRaid Software Guide](http://www.lsi.com/DistributionSystem/AssetDocument/files/docs/techdocs/storage_stand_prod/sas/mr_sas_sw_ug.pdf) Page 3-27 has what I think you're looking for.

> MegaCli –LDRecon

Note that I've never done this and I don't think that it's a particularly good idea.  Make a backup of your data first.  Good Luck!

-Dave